# Trouble to verify if a number is already in a column

Tags: python

i was trying to verify if a number from a list already exist in a column matrix, but still repeating. Someone can help me?

```
import random
    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    matrix = [[None for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]

def createMatrix():
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            cop = numbers[:]
            random.shuffle(cop)
            while matrix[i][j] is None:
                temp = veriCol(matrix, j, cop)
                if temp == 0:
                    matriz[i] = cop
                else: 
                    return None


def veriCol(matrix, col, value):
    tmp = 0
    for l in range(9):
        #print("Vc {}".format(l)),
        if value == matrix[l][col]:
            tmp = 1

    return tmp


createMatrix()
for i in range(9):
    print(matriz[i])
```

Comment: is it a must to use pythons list? using numpy would be far easier

Comment: Your logic reshuffles the list of numbers for every column.  You should move the two lines `cop = numbers[:]; random.shuffle(cop)`outside of the `for j in ...` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maintain a list of sets for column values used. The verification of a new "shuffled" line could be done more directly. Same thing for the sub-matrix groups although you'll need to use an indirection (or a complex index calculation) to map positions to group sets:

```
import random

def createMatrix():
    matrix  = []
    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    groups  = [ [0,0,0, 1,1,1, 2,2,2] ] * 3
    groups += [ [3,3,3, 4,4,4, 5,5,5] ] * 3
    groups += [ [6,6,6, 7,7,7, 8,8,8] ] * 3
    while len(matrix) < 9:
        matrix    = []
        colSets   = [ set() for _ in range(9) ]
        groupSets = [ set() for _ in range(9) ]
        for row in range(9):
            for _ in range(133496): # try multiple permutations for row (36.79%)
                random.shuffle(numbers)
                if any( n in used for n,used in zip(numbers,colSets) ):
                    continue # column conflict
                if any( n in groupSets[g] for n,g in zip(numbers,groups[row]) ):
                    continue # sub-matrix group conflict
                matrix.append(numbers.copy())
                for n,used in zip(numbers,colSets):     used.add(n)
                for n,g    in zip(numbers,groups[row]): groupSets[g].add(n)
                break
            if len (matrix) == row: break # restart if failed to produce a row
    return matrix

sudoku = createMatrix()
for line in sudoku:
    print(line)
```

If you're trying to generate a random latin square, a faster technique would be to randomize a working baseline rather than iteratively checking the validity of random number sets in a trial/error process:

```
import random

numbers = random.sample(range(1,10),9)
cols    = random.sample(range(9),9)
rows    = random.sample(range(9),9)
matrix  = [[numbers[(r+c)%9] for c in cols] for r in rows]

for line in matrix: print(line)  

[8, 9, 1, 7, 6, 4, 5, 3, 2]
[5, 2, 9, 6, 4, 3, 1, 8, 7]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 5, 1, 7, 9, 3]
[1, 7, 2, 4, 3, 8, 9, 5, 6]
[7, 3, 4, 5, 1, 9, 6, 2, 8]
[3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 6, 8, 4, 9]
[4, 5, 8, 9, 2, 7, 3, 6, 1]
[9, 6, 7, 3, 8, 5, 2, 1, 4]
[6, 8, 3, 1, 9, 2, 4, 7, 5]
```

To explain this one, it is best to start with a simple matrix of sequential indexes where each row is offset by one more than the preceding row:

```
matrix = [ [(r+c)%9 for c in range(9)] for r in range(9) ]

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] # base row
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0] # offset by 1
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1] # offset by 2
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2] # ....
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

As you can see each row has indexes 0 to 8 (so no repetitions) and each column also has indexes 0 to 8 with no repetition because of offsetting.

Now if we create a list of numbers from 1 to 9 and shuffle it, we can replace the indexes in the matrix by the corresponding number in the shuffled list. Since each index maps to a different number, the resulting matrix will not have any repetitions on lines or columns.

```
numbers = random.sample(range(1,10),9) # [1, 5, 9, 8, 3, 7, 6, 2, 4]
matrix  = [ [numbers[i] for i in row] for row in matrix ]

[1, 5, 9, 8, 3, 7, 6, 2, 4]
[5, 9, 8, 3, 7, 6, 2, 4, 1]
[9, 8, 3, 7, 6, 2, 4, 1, 5]
[8, 3, 7, 6, 2, 4, 1, 5, 9]
[3, 7, 6, 2, 4, 1, 5, 9, 8]
[7, 6, 2, 4, 1, 5, 9, 8, 3]
[6, 2, 4, 1, 5, 9, 8, 3, 7]
[2, 4, 1, 5, 9, 8, 3, 7, 6]
[4, 1, 5, 9, 8, 3, 7, 6, 2]
```

Finally we can shuffle the rows to get a more random organization of the matrix

```
random.shuffle(matrix)

[5, 9, 8, 3, 7, 6, 2, 4, 1]
[9, 8, 3, 7, 6, 2, 4, 1, 5]
[1, 5, 9, 8, 3, 7, 6, 2, 4]
[7, 6, 2, 4, 1, 5, 9, 8, 3]
[2, 4, 1, 5, 9, 8, 3, 7, 6]
[6, 2, 4, 1, 5, 9, 8, 3, 7]
[4, 1, 5, 9, 8, 3, 7, 6, 2]
[8, 3, 7, 6, 2, 4, 1, 5, 9]
[3, 7, 6, 2, 4, 1, 5, 9, 8]
```

and the columns:

```
cols   = random.sample(range(9),9) # [7, 4, 3, 0, 8, 1, 2, 5, 6]
matrix = [[matrix[r][c] for c in cols] for r in range(9)]

[4, 7, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 6, 2]
[1, 6, 7, 9, 5, 8, 3, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 8, 1, 4, 5, 9, 7, 6]
[8, 1, 4, 7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 9]
[7, 9, 5, 2, 6, 4, 1, 8, 3]
[3, 5, 1, 6, 7, 2, 4, 9, 8]
[6, 8, 9, 4, 2, 1, 5, 3, 7]
[5, 2, 6, 8, 9, 3, 7, 4, 1]
[9, 4, 2, 3, 8, 7, 6, 1, 5]
```

The solution (above) combines these steps into a single list comprehension but uses exactly the same approach.

Using this approach, it is also possible to produce a random sudoku board (with the 3x3 block constraint). The formula for the offsets is a bit more complex and the shuffling of rows and columns can only be done within and between block groups but the overall technique is the same.

```
from random import sample
base  = 3  # Will generate any size of random sudoku board instantly
side  = base*base
nums  = sample(range(1,side+1),side) # random numbers
board = [[nums[(base*(r%base)+r//base+c)%side] for c in range(side) ] for r in range(side)]
rowGr = sample(range(base),base) # random rows/horizontal blocks
rows  = [ r for g in rowGr for r in sample(range(g*base,(g+1)*base),base) ] 
colGr = sample(range(base),base) # random column/vertical blocks
cols  = [ c for g in colGr for c in sample(range(g*base,(g+1)*base),base) ]            
board = [[board[r][c] for c in cols] for r in rows]

for line in board:print(line)
[7, 5, 3, 6, 9, 4, 1, 2, 8]
[6, 9, 4, 1, 2, 8, 7, 5, 3]
[1, 2, 8, 7, 5, 3, 6, 9, 4]
[2, 8, 7, 5, 3, 6, 9, 4, 1]
[5, 3, 6, 9, 4, 1, 2, 8, 7]
[9, 4, 1, 2, 8, 7, 5, 3, 6]
[8, 7, 5, 3, 6, 9, 4, 1, 2]
[3, 6, 9, 4, 1, 2, 8, 7, 5]
[4, 1, 2, 8, 7, 5, 3, 6, 9]
```

*This produces a random 9x9 sudoku in 0.2 milliseconds compared to the trial/error approach which takes 1 to 20 seconds (very random times)*

Like the latin square technique, this is based on a valid baseline board composed of indexes with the appropriate row, column and block constraints:

```
base  = 3
side  = base*base
board = [[(base*(r%base)+r//base+c)%side for c in range(side)] for r in range(side)]

for line in board: print(line)

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] # base row
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2] # offset by 3
[6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # offset by 6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0] # offset by 1
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3] # offset by 4
[7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] # offset by 7
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1] # offset by 2
[5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4] # offset by 5
[8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] # offset by 8
```

The rest is merely the substitution of indexes with shuffled numbers and the shuffling of rows columns and blocks.

Comment: I added explanations.

Comment: I need one more help. Inside this matrix, the number can't repeat in the 3 x 3 sub-matrix

Comment: Added a random sudoku generator based on the same technique.

Comment: It's weird, thw first code you wrote doesn't work.                                           
`colSets = [ set() for _ in range(9) ]`
`for i in range(9):`
     `cop = numbers[:]`
    ` random.shuffle(cop)`

Comment: It was not actual code, I just wrote it in the answer box to give you a hint.  Your original logic was missing a retry loop.  The createMatrix() function needs to be called repeatedly until it finds a solution (which could take a long time).  Hence the poor performance of that trial/error method.  I updated it but I don't believe you'll get good results with that (at least not in a reasonable time)

Comment: The trial and error approach will find a solution for a simple latin square relatively rapidly but, if you introduce the sub-matrix constraint, it may never finish.

Comment: It's ok, tanks dude!

Comment: Added the sub-matrix check to my original example. Surprisingly it doesn't take as long as I expected to get a solution (although response time will be random)

Comment: I try print the matrix and i get: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: `for line in matrix:print(line)` should never cause an index error (check your printing logic).  Also, I corrected a few typos in my last few edits, perhaps you picked up a version of my example with some bug in it.  It should be ok now.

Comment: `while len(matrix) < 9: createMatrix()` guarantees that the matrix will always have 9 lines. Update the question with your current code or create a new question. (the latter would be preferable at this point because SO is not a chat room and long discussions like this are frowned upon)

Answer (score 0):

Forget indexed loops unless you need indices for other purposes; embrace list comprehensions and `for .. in` loops.

```py
def is_number_in_column(number, column, matrix):
  return any(row[column] == number for row in matrix)
```

If your task is to put numbers so that there are no repeating numbers in any column, consider remembering the used up columns.

- You can place any sequence of numbers in the first row.
- In the second row, you should take out the number used in the first column (let it be *X*), shuffle the rest, then put the *X* at any random place except first.
- In the third row, you have two numbers used up, *X* from first column and *Y* from second. Cut them out, shuffle the rest, then put *X* at any position but first, and then *Y* at any position but second.

Etc; formulate this for the general case, it's easier that your current algorithm. Using a set instead of a list helps.